# Object in Object rotation ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, object, rotation, three.js

I'm trying to rotate a bunch of separate objects in a Array as 1 object.

Like this:

```
//call bodyparts in console
bodyParts
//This is the outcome
[THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh, THREE.Mesh];
```

for example i can call `bodyParts[0].rotation.x` to rotate them all seperately but I want to rotate them all at once.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was a pretty simple fix in the end..

I just used the Three.js `.add()` function to add my sub objects to one object and rotate that one!